# What is the difference between setview() and renderview()?

Tags: coldfusion-10, coldbox

I want to know the exact explanation for difference between setview() and renderview()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setview()` overrides the view set by convention (typically `views/handler/action.cfm`). This renders at the end of the event.

`renderview()` calls the view immediately, similar to a `cfinclude`. The rendering can be captured in a variable for later use.

See the [ColdBox wiki for Views & Layouts](http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Layouts-Views.cfm) for more information.